# Open a ppt from Sharepoint on command button click - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted to open ppt form SharePoint using the VBA, using the command button

if any one knows please help me.

Thanks...

I have similar code...below.. but its giving me the error

```
Dim PPT As PowerPoint.Application
Dim fileName As Variant
Dim WS1 As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Set WS1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4")
Set rng = WS1.Range("AA4")


Set PPT = New PowerPoint.Application
fileName = rng

PPT.Visible = True

'PPT.Presentations.Open fileName:="F:\Reports\" & Business_Plan.Value & ".ppt"
PPT.Presentations.Open fileName("AA4")
```

Comment: What is the error, and which line of code?

Comment: The `Presentations.Open` line that you've commented is the correct form of the method. The line that uses `fileName("AA4")` will cause an error. You should also check the value of `Business_Plan.Value` and make sure you're constructing a valid filename for PowerPoint to open. As @Comintern points out though, we need more information in order to help.

Comment: After remove fileName("AA4") to PPT.Presentations.Open filename I am getting the error as "Run time error -2147024894(80070002) Method "open of Object "Presentation Failed"

Comment: PPT.Presentations.Open fileName:=rng

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the value of "A2" in Sheet 1 is the entire Path+File Name (F:\Reports\FileName.ppt)

```
Sub openPowerP()
    Dim PPT As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim WS1 As Worksheet
    Set WS1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    fileName = WS1.Range("A2").Value
    Set PPT = New PowerPoint.Application
    PPT.Presentations.Open fileName
End Sub
```

The reference to powerpoint is needed of course.
[image: PowerPoint Reference]

Comment: Yes I have full sharePoint path in "AA4"

Comment: fileName = WS1.Range("AA4").

Comment: Is it not working for you? I tested the code and it works for me.

Comment: I am trying to open PPT from SharePoint, and in range("AA4 I have given full path nae

Comment: I have another code its open the PPT from SharePoint but after opening the PPT am getting the error as "run time error '- 2147467259 80004005 )': method open of object presentations failed"

Comment: Private Sub ManufacturingViwe_Click_1()
Dim PPT As PowerPoint.Application
Dim MyPresentation As Presentation
Dim fileName As Variant

Dim WS1 As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range

Set PPT = New PowerPoint.Application

Set WS1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set rng = WS1.Range("G5") ' SharePoint link is placed
   
    fileName = rng
    PPT.Visible = True

  PPT.Presentations.Open fileName
 
End Sub

Comment: The visible portion was giving me issues that's why i removed it. Once the Power Point open it automatically becomes visible. copy my code as it is and try it.

Comment: Ricardo, Thanks for your response even i am using below code also i am getting same error.    Dim PPT As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim WS1 As Worksheet
    Set WS1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    fileName = WS1.Range("I8").Value
    Set PPT = New PowerPoint.Application
    PPT.Presentations.Open fileName

Comment: I just tested the code on a new workbook and it works fine. Do you have the correct reference selected? Try it on a new workbook, copy the code in my answer as it is, put the entire filepath\filename on Cell A2 on Sheet1, select the PowerPoint Reference and try it.

Comment: Thanks for you time Ricardo, even after adding the References I am getting same error, I am able to open PPT from SharePoint after open I am getting error ""run time error '- 2147467259 80004005 )': method open of object presentations failed" " I am not able to identify where I am missing.

Comment: Thank you Ricardo yes its working fine, Thanks lot for your Valuable time..